# XBee S2C DigiMesh Networking

Tags: xbee, networking

I recently bought a Digi XBee S2C Development Kit. This is my first time with XBee radios and I'm working with DigiMesh as I will be using sleeping coordinators to make the entire network sleep.

I managed to communicate two modules in API 1 mode by giving them the same ID and Channel and the network is created automatically as far as I know. I also used the network discovery in XCTU so I can see all the nodes in the network.

I want to know if there's any way to scan for nodes with a different network ID than mine and request joining to that network or send some kind of package to the coordinator of the network. I will explain my scenario so maybe this makes some sense.

I have 'central units' that will have GSM connection and this unit will collect data from multiple 'sensor units'. The 'sensor units' will send data to the 'central unit' using DigiMesh. The problem is, If I have all the units with the same network ID there's a possibility that two 'central units' that are nearby (this is totally possible) have their XBee join to the other 'central unit' network because they all have the same ID, and this is not desired. So, I wanted to make some kind of associating mechanism like WPS on WiFi, you press a button on the 'sensor unit' and on the 'central unit' so the 'sensor unit' joins the 'central unit' network. Is there any way to achieve this? How is this problem approached generally?

My last resource is to have all the units with different IDs hard-coded but that's not desired because if I put a different 'central unit' I will have to reprogram all the 'sensor unit' IDs to join the new 'central unit'.